# append div on the fly (recursive)

Tags: jquery

i need to create a json, and whe i click on "add element" i need create a son of this and i can't figure that, i can add a sibling, using the $(".divClass") but i need to create a new element on the new div i create:
on the first option use

```
'click .opcion': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x++
    $(".eventos").append('<div id="a' + x + '">' +
        '<input type="text" name="izq[]"/>' +
        '<input type="text" name="der[]"/>' +
        '<a href="#" class="sumar">Sumar</a>' +
        '<a href="#" class="borrar">Borrar</a>' +
        '</div>'); //add input box

},
```

this work for i use $(".eventos") selector, but i use this ->

```
'click .sumar': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x++
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.append('<div id="a' + x + '">' +
        '<input type="text" name="izq[]"/>' +
        '<input type="text" name="der[]"/>' +
        '<a href="#" class="sumar">Sumar</a>' +
        '<a href="#" class="borrar">Borrar</a>' +
        '</div>'); //add input box
},
```

i put the text element but not the html element. and i don't know why

sorry i use meteor, but is jquery.

thanks!

Comment: please add some html as well, and if possible create a testable example snippet : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: try wrapping the parentNode in jquery  `$(e.currentTarget.parentNode)` - parentNode is a pure js object and as such would need to use appendChild (which expects child html objects rather html text) than instead of append

Comment: i try someting like https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbmzPX?editors=1011